# Upload files to RAM Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to make a small app that plays a sound every time i press a button, but the sounds have a small delay because they have to load from the SD (i think). Is there any way to upload the audio files to RAM memory every time i run the code, or any other idea to get rid of that delay?

Thank you!

```html
import pygame
pygame.init()

doSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/mnt/ramdisk/do.wav')

doSound.play()
```

Comment: Could you please share the relevant code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could try a RAMdisk: `mount -t tmpfs -o size=16m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk` and copy your sound file to `/mnt/ramdisk`

Comment: code added, sorry for that @Sebastian

Comment: I don't think this works... There is no difference. Or maybe i did something wrong. @MarkSetchell

Comment: You could try convert wav to a numpy array (so it is loaded at start time) when you start your app and then play it. Some relevant links to start are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778878/python-write-a-wav-file-into-numpy-float-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357992/how-to-generate-audio-from-a-numpy-array).

Comment: Solved! Link to the answer that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273722/pygame-sound-delay)